# System.LocalDataStoreElement[] memory allocation

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, memory-management, code-first

After many OutOfMemoryExceptions I run memory profiler. System.LocalDataStoreElement[] cunsumes 123 GB of memory. Application consumes 70 MB after initialization around. After work up some data, memory allocation is 700 MB (even after several GC.Collect() calls). I use Code-First Entity Framework 4.1 Update 1. Is this memory allocation common for Code-First?

Comment: ..."cunsumes 123 **GB** of memory"... - wish I had that much memory! ;)

Comment: I have just 8 GB. But all alocated blocks have 123 GB (info by profiler).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you hit the issue described in the [KB 2540745](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2540745) .

Comment: Thank you. It solved the problem. Hotfix is not public so contacting Microsoft technical support is necessary.